# How to minimize multiple if statements?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, reduce, code-cleanup

I'm doing a code cleanup and I want your **HELP**
The code creates units and place them in a unitPositionHashmap. Furthermore it reduces production value according to unit type. 
I'm looking for a way to reduce the amount of code and smarter way to structure this method, so I avoide almost dublicated code. 
[The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVR96.png)

Comment: First if statement is redundant. No impact on code. You can straight away remove it.

Comment: extract the test to a method, and pass the values and tested against values as parameters

Comment: @TavishAggarwal : `TheCityHashMap.getProduction()` could be null

Comment: Please add code and errors as **text** ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method having one if block and use parameters to fill in the variable values (p, GameConstants value (like ARCHER), ProductionAmount condition value (like 10). You'll have one if left in the makeUnit method, while having only one if in the new method.

Comment: Thank you very much